# Double Buffering in Java

Tags: java, doublebuffered

I found this code of double buffering on internet but it has no explaination. I am a little confused in this code.

- Why is the Image "i" used? What is its use if it is to be used once?
- Why are we assigning changing color to Foreground color,when we already have set color?
- What is g.drawImage() method doing?

Here is the code:

```
public void update(Graphics g)
{
    if(i==null)
    {
        i=createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
        graph=i.getGraphics();
    }

    graph.setColor(getBackground());
    graph.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(),getHeight());
    graph.setColor(getForeground());

    paint(graph);

    g.drawImage(i,0,0,this);
  }
```

Regards

Comment: Your code seems to be very incomplete making it difficult to tease out the logic, including where the g comes from (possibly passed from the JVM into a `paint(...)` or `paintComponent(...)` method?

Comment: and Swing JComponents are doublebuffered by default

Comment: OK, that edit gives more information but also generates more questions. One would rarely if ever override the `update(Graphics g)` method in a Swing application, and usually this would be done for AWT applications only. Your tag suggests that this question is about Swing -- please clarify.

Comment: that was a mistake. I apologise for that mistake. I am using it in applet

Comment: Then this tutorial is likely way out of date. I would use Swing and not AWT since as mKorbel notes, drawing in Swing is done via double buffering by default.

Comment: But when I use JApplet, the moving objects leave their mark behind. And every thing messes up

Comment: @Alfred: that has ***nothing*** to do with double buffering. You're asking the wrong question. Possibly you're not calling a super paint or paintComponent method. I suggest that you ask a new question with all these important details. Have you gone through the basic painting with Swing tutorials? Are you drawing in the `paintComponent(...)` method of a JPanel? Are you calling the super method on the first line of this method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The basic idea of Double Buffering is to create the image off screen then display it all at once.

[image: Double Buffering]

*From the java tutorials found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/doublebuf.html)*

The code you have there first creates an image on first way through to be your "Back Buffer" with this bit, i is likely a field such as

```
 private Image i;
 private Graphics graph;

 if(i==null)
{
    i=createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
    graph=i.getGraphics();
}
```

Then Paints the background color onto the image with this

```
graph.setColor(getBackground());
graph.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(),getHeight());
```

Then sets the front ready for drawing.

```
graph.setColor(getForeground());
paint(graph); /draws
```

Finally drawing the back Buffer over to the primary surface.

```
g.drawImage(i,0,0,this);
```

Comment: One question. I gets updated only once that is in the beginning. After that, it doesn't gets updated. Then why doesn't the `g.drawImage()` method prints new graphics always

Comment: @Alfred graph is a reference to `i`'s graphics class any change to that affects the image.

Comment: how graph became reference to image class?

Comment: @Alfred not image, Graphic class the one that will actually has the methods to draw the image also has a reference (by virtue of being retrieved from the image itself), back to the image on which it is meant to paint on.

Comment: Ok so you are directing me to the reference created in the i==null condition. Do you mean the reference created there by returning graphics object from image class using i.getGraphics()

Comment: thanks alot. :) please visit my other question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13586163/putting-java-applet-on-the-web

Answer (score 2):

The graphics operations are all performed on a `Graphics` obtained from `i`, which is a bitmap in memory.

When they're finished, the bitmap is drawn onto the "real" (screen) `Graphics` object `g`. So the user will never see half-finished drawing, which eliminates flicker.

The field `i` is allocated the first time and then reused, so it is not only used once.